# ARM template to create ASA job with javascript UDAs

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-stream-analytics, azure-rm-template

I have a stream analytics job which uses a number of javascript UDFs and UDAs. I would like to be able to deploy this using an Azure resource manager template.

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-function seems rather outdated and only describes `Scalar` functions, which I assume means UDFs.

Are there any documentation or examples showing how to create UDAs using an ARM template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UDAs you should use "type":"Aggregate" in your Functions section of the template. Example below.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "type": "Aggregate",  //Aggregate type.
    "properties": {
      "inputs": [ // accumulate input parameter(s).
        {
          "dataType": "any", // Input data type
        }
      ],
      "output": { // Output
        "dataType": "any" // Output data type
      },
      "binding": {
        "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/JavascriptUdf",
        "properties": { // Aggregate definition
          "script": "function main() {
                          this.init = function () {
                              this.state = 0;
                          }

                          this.accumulate = function (value, timestamp) {
                              this.state += value;
                          }

                          this.computeResult = function () {
                              return this.state;
                          }
                     }"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Microsoft docs reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-aggregate

Comment: Thank you, it seems it's finally documented now.

Answer (score 2):

If you have created a job with UDA already, use PowerShell command Get-AzureRMStreamAnalyticsJob to retrieve the job definition and you will find out how UDA is defined.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-monitor-and-manage-jobs-use-powershell

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for UDAs, returning simply `"Properties": null` instead of the code. The code is returned correctly for UDFs using the method you describe.